# Flutter (Dart): Highlight or select a widget (Tile or any element) onLongPress event

Tags: listview, dart, uigesturerecognizer, flutter, long-press

Does anyone know how to implement a selection of the elements located inside a `ListView Class` in Flutter. All elements present in my list are constructed as

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
         Navigator.of(context).push(
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new SomePage(someId))
                );
      }, 
      onLongPress: () {
         //how to implement this to highlight that particular widget as selected
      }
  }
```

When I tap over it I open a new page showing/preforming some operations and is all good. But when long pressed I need to select it and then provide a comparison in between all selected elements. Because my elements are objects is easy to process them but I can not select or mark it as selected on long press.

The selected widget can be anything from tile, row, shape...any widget in general.

thanks in advance...

Comment: Already answer follow the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600048/flutter-listtile-enable-multi-select-onlongpress

Comment: indeed :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Flutter Rocks Blog](https://flutter.rocks/): specially this one: [Implementing adaptive master-detail layouts in Flutter](https://flutter.rocks/2018/01/28/implementing-adaptive-master-detail-layouts/). It has a very good an easy to follow example on how to handle the selection of ListTiles within a ListView, by passing different routes.