# Flutter ListTile enable multi-select onLongPress

Tags: flutter

I would like to achieve similar things in Google Keep.

[image: Enable multi-select onLongPress]

How can I enable multiple selections on long press and change the header buttons, so that I can delete those selected items later?

My current Dart code :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Card(
      child: new Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
        new ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.info),
          title: new Text(item.name),
          subtitle: new Text(item.description),
          trailing: new Text(item.dateTime.month.toString()),
          onTap: () => _openEditDialog(context, item),
          onLongPress: // what should I put here,
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

when the user does a long press the [ListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) must change the selected property to true and vice versa and the Card Color must be Changed to Something like [Grey[300]](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Colors-class.html)

```
class cardy extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _cardyState createState() => new _cardyState();
}

class _cardyState extends State<cardy> {
  var isSelected = false;
  var mycolor=Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Card(
      color: mycolor,
      child: new Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
        new ListTile(
            selected: isSelected,
            leading: const Icon(Icons.info),
            title: new Text("Test"),
            subtitle: new Text("Test Desc"),
            trailing: new Text("3"),
            onLongPress: toggleSelection // what should I put here,
            )
      ]),
    );
  }

  void toggleSelection() {
    setState(() {
      if (isSelected) {
        mycolor=Colors.white;
        isSelected = false;
      } else {
        mycolor=Colors.grey[300];
        isSelected = true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

EDIT: if you want to get the Border coloring effect make the column Inside the Container and set the decoration property to a variable and call it **border** and Edit the select method

```
void toggleSelection() {
    setState(() {
      if (isSelected) {
        border=new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(color: Colors.white));
        mycolor = Colors.white;
        isSelected = false;
      } else {
        border=new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(color: Colors.grey));
        mycolor = Colors.grey[300];
        isSelected = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: oh ok.. that means I need to implement the box styling and header by myself.. I thought there is an easy configuration for this.. thanks

Comment: @Mrye, have you succeed to recreate what you wanted to do, ie first long press do the first selection and then, single ontap select the others? If so, do you mind to show how? Thanks

Comment: @David i have used inheritedwidget for this.. not sure the best way though.. can refer to my https://github.com/yousoff92/flutter-firebase-crud-app/blob/management-app/lib/screens/item.dart

Comment: According to this short clip and the code, I have to long press all three tabs to select each of them but the desired behaviour is: I long press once, and just tap any of the others to add or remove selection

Answer (score -1):

I made a similar implementation a couple of days ago. Long-press on any item in the list to activate the selection, then single-tap to select afterwards. Once the desired items have been selected, tap the delete button to remove all selected items from the list.

CODE:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MultiSelect());

class MultiSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  const MultiSelect({super.key});

  @override
  State<MultiSelect> createState() => _MultiSelectState();
}

class _MultiSelectState extends State<MultiSelect> {
  existsInTrashCan(Course course) => trashCan.contains(course);
  List<Course> trashCan = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.cyan.shade900,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: trashCan.isEmpty
            ? AppBar(
                title: const Text('Multi-Delete'),
                centerTitle: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
              )
            : AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                leading: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      trashCan.clear();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                title: Text(trashCan.length.toString()),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        coursesData
                            .removeWhere((item) => trashCan.contains(item));
                        trashCan.clear();
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete))
                ],
              ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: coursesData.length,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(height: 5),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return PrettyCard(
                  name: coursesData[index].name,
                  isSelected: existsInTrashCan(coursesData[index]),
                  trashCan: trashCan,
                  onTap: () {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Single Tap!'),
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    ));
                  },
                  onDelete: () {
                    if (trashCan.contains(coursesData[index])) {
                      trashCan.remove(coursesData[index]);
                      setState(() {});
                    } else {
                      trashCan.add(coursesData[index]);
                      setState(() {});
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PrettyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final bool isSelected;
  final void Function()? onDelete;
  final void Function()? onTap;
  final List trashCan;

  const PrettyCard(
      {Key? key,
      required this.name,
      required this.isSelected,
      this.onDelete,
      this.onTap,
      required this.trashCan})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 2),
      child: Card(
        surfaceTintColor: isSelected ? Colors.black : null,
        color: Colors.cyan.shade900,
        child: ListTile(
          dense: true,
          selected: isSelected,
          onTap: trashCan.isNotEmpty ? onDelete : onTap,
          onLongPress: onDelete,
          tileColor: Colors.cyan.shade900,
          selectedColor: Colors.white,
          selectedTileColor: Colors.cyan.shade900,
          title: Text(name),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.cyan.shade50,
                  width: 3,
                  style: isSelected ? BorderStyle.solid : BorderStyle.none)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Course {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  Course({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
}

List<Course> coursesData = [
  Course(id: '1', name: 'MTH'),
  Course(id: '2', name: 'STS'),
  Course(id: '3', name: 'ACC'),
  Course(id: '4', name: 'ETH'),
  Course(id: '5', name: 'PHY'),
  Course(id: '6', name: 'CSC'),
];
```

Refer to this repo: https://github.com/acromondx/FlutterVortex/tree/main/multi_select

[image: demo]