# Flutter pick multiple contacts from custom phone book instead of loading all contacts into app

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I just want functionality where I can

1. Click the button
2. opens mobile contact list in multiple select mode
3. I can   select multiple contacts
4. return back to app with a list of selected    names+numbers

I have tried different libraries but all of them is for single phone picker, they didn't have multiple select options.

Comment: you can use this contacts_service package which will give you the list of contacts from the device and you can develop the ui in flutter itself for multiple select option. check this link for multi select option : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600962/12000053

Comment: i have checked it already. contact_service first loads contacts which takes time, so user have to wait untill it loads all contacts then display . i just want to prevent from this thing and want to select direclty from phone book multiple number. I am able to select single number but can't select multiple by using these packages.... 
 fluttercontactpicker: ^4.6.0    #app craches
  native_contact_picker: ^0.0.6    # pickes single number
  flutter_native_contact_picker: ^0.0.3  #picks single number

Comment: @AbdullahButt I am facing the same problem, did you find a solution?